# Survival analysis large number of small batches

Tags: survival, cox-model

I have a group of >10,000 right-censored survival cases, composed of a large number of small batches, with 1 to 7 cases in each batch.  Failure rate overall is low, with 95% survival at maximum time.  I would like to determine the effect of batch on survival, i.e. whether some batches are more predisposed to failure than others.  Obviously with these numbers, I cannot determine **which** batches are more prone to failure, but just want to get some idea of the contribution of batch membership.  There are two covariates I would like to include in the model.  I am using R for this analysis.

Comment: It's more important to know the number of failure events in your sample. Failures drive statistical power for time-to-event analyses, regardless of the number of controls. Are you saying there are 200 or more observed failures?

Comment: Yes, there are more than 600 observed failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want some sort of random effects model.  One option is the models with Normal batch effects on the log hazard scale that the `coxme` package fits

Comment: Thank you, that looks very promising.  I will try to get my head around the coxme vignettes to before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quantify the batch effect, batch needs to be an explanatory variable. However, with such high survival, it is likely that you have batches with 100 % survival. In this case there will be nothing to analyze. I think the best for you is simply to visualize the survival per batch with Kaplan-Meier curves.